# string array omiting characters z and y

Tags: c++, arrays, string, encryption

im doing an assignment for my lab which has to do with encrypting a string into a text file from another file, and it works good but my only problem is that when i encrypt or decrypt the encryption omits the letter Z and Y. I've tried changing a couple of things but nothing works, please if you know how to explain because i am lost.

this is my code so far:

```
 #include iostream
==
 #include fstream
==
 #include cstring
==
 #include string
==
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;
    const int SIZE=150;
    char file[SIZE];
    char message[SIZE+1];
    char letter;  
    char alphabet[]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L',
            'M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','\0'};



    cout<<"Enter the message you want to encrypt: "<<endl;     //getmessage
    cin.getline(message,SIZE,'\n');

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(message);i++){
       if(islower(message[i]))                               //change to 
            message[i]=toupper(message[i]);                 //uppercase
    }


    outputFile.open("textoNoEncrypt.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(message);i++){                  //copy message to 
       outputFile.put(message[i]);                      //file
     }
    outputFile.close();

    inputFile.open("textoNoEncrypt.txt");
    if (inputFile.is_open()){
         int i=0;
        while (!(inputFile=='\0')){
            inputFile>>file[i];                       //reading and copying
            i++;                                     //data from file        
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();

    outputFile.open("textoEncrypt.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(file);i++){
        int j=0;
        int P=0;
        int index=0;
        bool found=false;
        while(!found){
            if(file[i]==alphabet[j]){
                P=j;
                index=(P+3)%26;                     //encrypting message
                file[i]=alphabet[index];        
                found=true;
                cout<<j<<" ";
            }
        j++;
        }
        outputFile.put(file[i]);
    }
    outputFile.close();

    cout<<message<<endl;                        //show original message
    cout<<file<<endl;                           //show encrypted message

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `#include iostream` doesn't compile. Use `#include <iostream>` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: If your code really works, then you should better ask at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for improvement.

Comment: ... Otherwise the right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I'd start by tossing out all the file IO and reducing this to just an input string, your rotation algorithm, and an output string to console. If that works, you're ahead of the game. If it doesn't, you just tossed out a *ton* of io code that is cluttering the problem and can focus on fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cause by the P+3 line

Comment: Thats actually what i need to rotate the position of the letters, i dont thinks its that